zsh interprets command as whole string whereas bash / dash do not
Piece of script I need to run in various shells:
command="/sbin/traceroute -M tcp -f 255 -m 255 -q 1 -w 1 -p 80 google.fr"
result=`$command`

Result in bash and dash as expected, variable $result contains command output.
Result in zsh:
zsh: no such file or directory: /sbin/traceroute -M tcp -f 255 -m 255 -q 1 -w 1 -p 80 google.fr

Running the following in zsh works so I can confirm that I have that binary and that zsh is able to find it:
eval "$command"

Now I've tried various versions:
result=`$command`
result=`${command}`
result=$($command)
result=$(${command})

Each of the above test does not work in zsh.
While I do understand that zsh interprets my command variable as whole string and thus doesn't find the command, I wonder how this has to be achieved properly in a portable way accros zsh/bash/dash, preferably without eval for security reasons.

zsh doesn't do word-splitting when expanding variables, so you don't have to quote your variables like you do in bash. But it also has this result.

Trying to write shell that runs on zsh and something else is usually an exercise in frustration. Pick one shell and target it (sh + running zsh in sh emulation mode might be feasible, but zsh doesn't claim to be fully posix compatible even then).

I actually searched duplicates before, but there are way to many results in SO for this. Finally found [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] && setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT to make zsh behave like bash... @Shawn indeed, highly frustrating !

@OrsirisdeJong Also, more generally, storing commands in variables is just a bad idea, even if you aren't trying to be cross-shell compatible. Variables are for storing data, functions are for storing commands. See BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!" and many previous questions.

@GordonDavisson Well I do need to construct a command from various variables, and return it's result into a variable. How am I supposed to do that ?

@OrsirisdeJong Capturing the output to a variable is easy, just use result=$(whatever). Dynamically creating a command can be much more difficult, and depends on 1) exactly how the command needs to change based on those various variables, and 2) what shells you need it to work in. There are some suggestions in the FAQ I linked, but they may not work in shells other than bash. Without more info about exactly what you're trying to accomplish, I can't really say more.

@GordonDavisson As said, I did succeed by setting SH_WORD_SPLIT. My script https://github.com/deajan/tcpping now works on bash/dash/zsh. So no need to go further.
